# Emphasising that a date is near

Tags: writing-style

What is a good way to emphasise that a particular date is near or coming very close? For example, suppose today is the 22 of May and there is the submission date for a project is on the 25 of May. I could just say:

> As the deadline of the submission is on the 25 of May, we should work
>   faster.

The date 25 of May is near to some people but may not be near to others. If I add in the word "near" this way:

> As the deadline of the submission is *near* on the 25 of May, we should
>   work faster.

Would my last sentence be grammatically and semantically correct?

Comment: I hope this is only an example and you do *not* believe that a deadline can be reached by *working faster*.

Comment: Yes, this is an example. Perhaps trying an alternative method would be a better way to reach a deadline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I'm trying to motivate people to pay attention to things like this I usually say that the deadline is *looming*.  It conveys a sense of impending danger; other things that often *loom* are storms, battles, and obstacles.

You could also say that the deadline is *imminent* or *fast approaching*.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the way you put it as *looming*. Thank you so much! +1!!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably put something like:

```
As the deadline for the submission is approaching rapidly, 
we should do without eating and sleeping until then.
```

The distinction of "approaching rapidly" has a sense of urgency about it, and not specifying the deadline means that people who subconsciously ignore it until it is actually May 25th do not have that option.

And not eating or sleeping for 3 days is probably not the answer to hitting a deadline. Just dead.